# Looking for open source flash image rotator or tools to create one

Tags: flash, banner

I want to put a flash banner(slider) to show a bunch of products iteratively. And I want it to allow interaction so the user can interrupt image looping and choose what she wants to see and what images to show how long it will be shown should be configurable. I already googled for 'flashe banner / slider' but with no luck. Is there any open source projects that can offer this kind of feature? Or tools that can help me to create one.

I remember seen some websites who are using this kind of stuff to show several images repeatedly in one flash object. Unfortunately I couldn't recall which sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the JW image rotator : http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-image-rotator/
I haven't used it but do use their video player, and it's quite good.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't absolutely need flash, you should consider doing it in Javascript. Jquery makes that easy, here's a short list of options:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

Here's another:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/